# increase height of jQuery Mobile buttons

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'd like to increase the height of a few buttons created in jQuery Mobile, but CSS like the following is not working:

```
a[data-role="button"] {
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

Is there another way to do this? Perhaps apply a new height dynamically using jQuery and then call a function to redraw the button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This worked for my jQuery mobile app:

```
.ui-btn { height: 200px; font-size: 48px; }
```

But make sure that the css is occurring after the jquery mobile css is loaded (specifically: jquery.mobile.structure.css )

If it still gives you trouble, try wrapping the buttons in a container and use:

```
#container-id .ui-btn { height: 200px; font-size: 48px; }
```

If it STILL gives you trouble, you can always (not recommended) use an !important statement:

```
.ui-btn { height: 200px !important; font-size: 48px !important; }
```

But again, "important" statements are REALLY not recommended, i usually only use them as sanity checks to make sure I am selecting the right element while debugging.

EDIT:

If you want the dynamic route:

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  styles = { 'height': '200px', 'font-size': '48px' };
  $('.ui-btn').css(styles);
});
```

Should work... although now that I think about it I think jquery mobile does some javascript processing (I know it wraps your markup in a div with a reference to the current page url).

Comment: Works when I do the important tag, so I guess I just have to play with the order of my CSS files, or I'll try setting the height dynamically. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: np -- yeah I think the "mobile.structure" css file is included in some other file. If you're using inline css try moving the <style> block to the end of the <head> block. If you're using HTML5 (e.g. your doctype--the first thing in your file-- is "<!DOCTYPE html>") you can put the "style" block anywhere you want inside the <html> open/close tags, so you could conceivably put it at the end of the file.

Comment: @DrewDara-Abrams FYI -- added a possible dynamic solution.

Comment: I tried this solution, and it seems to be increasing the button size without increasing the font size in the button. Also it is jeopardizing the rest of the layout, like a listview that is showing up after the buttons.

Comment: @SamikR Check to see if you have a more specific CSS rule overriding your style. You can use the developer tools/firebug on chrome/firefox to see if another rule is overriding this one. You might have to change the selector. Perhaps your buttons are contained in a div, you could set the id on the div and change the selector to be `$('#div-id .ui-btn')`. If that doesn't work, try using `important` in your css, like `#div-id .ui-btn { font-size: 48px !important; }`

Comment: I think adding height to .ui-btn is not a good idea because as @SamikR  pointed out it is also applied to list items... Also changing height only is not enough, you need to change font size and icon position...

Comment: Hi can i know how i can change the size of the textfiled in the similar way, which wil reflect on all the textfield in my application

Answer (score 4):

The code below worked for me. If your button is:

```
    <a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-theme="d" class="big">Big button</a>
```

Then big and ui-btn-inner can have the following styles:

```
    .big { height: 80px;}
    .big .ui-btn-inner { padding-top:25px; }
```

Added padding so the text would appear to be center-aligned. This way the button style doesn't change globally and you have the control where you want to change the button. Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: The '.ui-btn-inner' selector allowed me to increase the size of the text on the button, whilst the '.ui-btn' selector allowed me to increase the height of the button. Cheers.